# Check if cursor is end of input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cursor

What I am trying to do is when I put the email address like test@example.com, test@example.co.uk, etc, and I hit on the space, I want to check that if the cursor is at the end of the input text before I could add HTML in the element.

```
if (selectionEndofText) {
  if (e.which == 32) {
    $('#oI').append('<div class="vR"><span class="vN" data-hovercard-name="'+name+'" data-hovercard-email="'+email+'" data-hovercard-owner-id="137"><div class="vT">'+name+'</div><div class="vM"></div></span><input name="to" type="hidden" value="<'+name+'>"></div>');
    $('.vR').insertBefore('#domodal_email_receipt');
    $('#domodal_email_receipt').val('');
  }
}
```

Full code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#domodal_email_receipt', function(e) {
  var fullname = $(this).val();
  var name = fullname.split(' <');
  var selectionEndofText = $(this).val().length;
  var name = name[0];
  var email = '';

  if (fullname.indexOf('<') > -1) {
    email = fullname.split('<');
    email = email[1].replace('>', '');
  }

  alert("selectionEndofText................."+selectionEndofText);

  //if (!selectionEndofText)
    if (e.which == 32) {
      $('#oI').append('<div class="vR"><span class="vN" data-hovercard-name="'+name+'" data-hovercard-email="'+email+'" data-hovercard-owner-id="137"><div class="vT">'+name+'</div><div class="vM"></div></span><input name="to" type="hidden" value="<'+name+'>"></div>');
      $('.vR').insertBefore('#domodal_email_receipt');
      $('#domodal_email_receipt').val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to checking space keyword in the if statement, you can also check the caret position with `.selectionStart` that returns a number. So, if the current position is equal to the length, that means it is in the end of the input.

To clear the input, use a `setTimeOut` to make it run last. Otherwise, there will be a space inside it.

```
if (e.which == 32 && selectionEndofText === this.selectionStart) {
  $('#oI').append('<div class="vR"><span class="vN" data-hovercard-name="'+name+'" data-hovercard-email="'+email+'" data-hovercard-owner-id="137"><div class="vT">'+name+'</div><div class="vM"></div></span><input name="to" type="hidden" value="<'+name+'>"></div>');
  $('.vR').insertBefore('#domodal_email_receipt');

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#domodal_email_receipt').val('');
  }, 0);

}
```